# Why ulu dhvani(sound) is given?

Tags: tradition, puja

Namaskar,

We see Ulu dhvani(sound) during puja. This is also called ululation in english. Why do we need to do that? I don't have any religious book where I can know this. So it will be great if I got answer.

You can hear it in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AfXauKtkiIM) video.

Hare krishna.

Comment: My answer may not be correct, but a guess. It is also followed in Kerala, as blowing the "Ola", probably to drive away evil spirits pervading the air. It  sounds  like the vibrating wind out of a Conch.A warning signal.

Comment: Please explain/translate what ulu dhoni is. It is not obvious to those outside your language/culture.

Comment: Making sound like OOLOO during religious occasions is more of a bengali culture/.I don't think its based on Sastras.During marriages,Pujas the ladies do it.And,May be Narasimhan's reasoning is correct.

Comment: @moonstar2001, after reading Rickross' comment I understood what it is.. maybe it should be called 'oloolooloo dhvani'.. dhvani = sound

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'Ulu dhoni' is used know others about a good news. The 'Ulu' can make loud sound from the tongue which can go far away. So anyone from distance can easily recognize  a good thing happening around. 
This is a tradition only by the Bengali Hindu community. They make Ulu during their social and religious festival.